# How to use isNaN here properly?

Tags: javascript, forms, background, numbers

I have two fields. The first one is a name field and the other one is a number field.  I want to check if the number field is numeric, if not, then select() will be used and background turns to yellow instead of blue. Somehow I'm not getting what I want.

```
window.onload=function()
{

idUser = document.getElementById("user");

document.getElementById("form").onsubmit=function()
{
    if(idUser.value == "")
    {
        alert("Username Required");
        idUser.focus();

        return false;
    }

birYear = document.getElementById("birthyear");

    if(isNaN(birYear))
    {
        birYear.select();
        alert("number");
        return false;
    }

}
}
```

I'm using `alert("number");` just to double check if it's doing it properly. I don't need an alert but somehow if I put number or text both ways it's just alert number which means I'm not doing what I want right.

Thanks in advance for people giving me a hand.

Comment: You just give an message as Invalid Birth Year in alert box.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to get value :

```
birYear = document.getElementById("birthyear").value;
```

`document.getElementById("birthyear")` give you the control where as `document.getElementById("birthyear").value` give the value of that input(or any other) control..

and `isNan()` is for value not control ....

**Edit :**

you can do that by changing the style : `document.getElementById("birthyear").style.background-color = "yellow";`

Comment: thanks that helps. but how about if I want it to be a yellow background instead of blue though?

Comment: you can do that by changing the style : `document.getElementById("birthyear").style.background-color = "yellow";`